# Update all ID's in 1 API call - Elastisearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I want to update all ID's under  particular Index and Type with 1 query fire. I tried to look into _bulk and _update but was not able to find the exact way to do. Can someone direct me what call should I make it to update all ID's json with new key-value.

```js
Previous JSON:

{     "_index": "ABC",
      "_type": "EFG",
      "_id": "000014484",
      "_score": 1,
      "_source": {
          "file_attachment__name__s": null,
          "file_attachment__contenttype__s": null
      }
}

Intended JSON with every ID's:
{     "_index": "ABC",
      "_type": "EFG",
      "_id": "000014484",
      "_score": 1,
      "_source": {
          "file_attachment__name__s": null,
          "file_attachment__contenttype__s": null,
          "cat" : "yes"
      }
}
```

Comment: I assume you don't want to update the IDs, but the documents? You'll have to [reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) your whole index

Comment: @AdamMichalik I want to update the ID's with new Json key value. Will reindex help me to update all ID's document with {"cat" : "yes} in existing JSON?